# Java Parse JSON from URL: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I am trying to parse json data (as shown in agency.json) from an url using Java (as shown in ReadJSON.java) but I get an error:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
    at com.demo.json.ReadJSON.main(ReadJSON.java:43)**

My attempt is shown as below:

agency.json:

```
{

    "agency": [
      {
        "agency_id": "11111",
        "agency_name": "UP"
      },
      {
        "agency_id": "22222",
        "agency_name": "UPTK"
      },
      {
        "agency_id": "33333",
        "agency_name": "UAD"
      },
      {
        "agency_id": "44444",
        "agency_name": "Testing Agency"
      },
      {
        "agency_id": "55555",
        "agency_name": "Agency's name with quote"
      }
    ]

}
```

ReadJSON.java:

```
package com.demo.json;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;

public class ReadJSON {

  private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
      return json;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://10.11.123.12:8001/json/testing/agency.json");

    JSONArray agenciesArray = (JSONArray) json.get("agency");

    for (int i=0; i<agenciesArray.size(); i++) {
        agenciesArray.get(i);
    } 
  }
}
```

I tried to search for solution in stackoverflow forum but mostly are parsing from file. Please guide me on how to solve the exception. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the import from `import org.json.simple.JSONArray;` to `import org.json.JSONArray;`

Comment: Hi @Wilder Pereira, thanks for the solution, it solves the exception but any idea how can I display the agency_id and agency_name?

Comment: So you're not getting any other errors and want to print your data ?

Comment: Yes. I tried to print i but I can only get 0,1,2,3,4.

Comment: Print the values of ```agenciesArray.get(i).getString("agency_id")```and  ```agenciesArray.get(i).getString("agency_name")```

Answer (score 0):

Check your import statements at the top of your source file.

You probably have a line saying:

import org.json.JSONArray;
It should instead be:

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
If you are working in eclipse, or any other intelligent IDE, the problem probably happened when you started typing the line starting with JSONArray. At that point, the IDE would show you different possibilities of importing the class JSONArray. You have one in org.json.JSONArray and one in org.json.simple.JSONArray. The latter is the right one, but you choose the first one and your IDE automatically added an import line at the top of your source java file.

From the exception the problem is quite apparent, the exception tells you that your obj object cannot be cast to a org.json.JSONArray object as it is really a org.json.simple.JSONArray object. (Note that there is a different between the two).

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explanation, @karthi keyan